# Save before closing a document

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-app

I have developed an Office add-in. It contains an editor where users could type and save a text.

I want to realise a feature: 1) One option is, when a user closes a spreadsheet/document, I want to remind them of saving the text on the add-in (by simply clicking on a button of the add-in); 2) another option is, when a user closes a spreadsheet/document, the text on add-in is systematically saved.

In either case, we need to be able to listen to the event when a document is closed, or a browser tab is closed (if it is Office Online).

Does anyone know how to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no close document event API yet. You can make your API request [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). The event to intercept document/tab/window close action is not possible consistently because the process itself could end and also JS APIs are asynchronous in nature.

The Word API offers [save](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.4_OpenSpec/reference/word/document.md#save) API that could be used to save the document. Word also offers `document.saved` (Boolean) API to check periodically and save the document if that matches the requirement. Excel also offers `workbook.saved` API (still in preview) but not the save() API.

Comment: Do you have any doc about `workbook.saved` of Excel?